# Subscribing to httpClient get method results in an XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I've setup a new application with angular 5 (latest version) and I run into the following error:

```
Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document.
```

I can provide code if needed but the error already occurs for a simple:

```
this.http.get('https://google.com').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error, and getting the pre-flight response error. Please add more code for an explanation.

Comment: Try `http.get('https://google.com', {responseType: text'}).subscribe...`

Answer (score 0):

use this to get an Observable of string

```
const options: { responseType: 'text'};
this.httpClient.get(url, options)
```

and you have to specify type for json for example

```
const options: { responseType: 'text' as 'json'};
this.httpClient.get(url, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error:

> Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The
> response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a
> document. error.

From the little research that I did, this seems to happening if one of the JS assets on your page is making a synchronous request. Sometimes, a tracking library included on the page is making synchronous calls and is messing up with the angular HTTP requests. I still haven't found the work around for it though :-)